# How to change base path for assets, images, etc

Tags: next.js

I need my app to work well on a subfolder of the main domain. Exactly [here](https://www.sergiosdorje.com/out/index.html)
At first I had a plenty of errors of scripts, css and images not being loaded.

I added the following to next.config.js:

```
basePath: "/out",
```

Now scripts and css are working well when exported, they have the /out/ in the path.

However the files do not have yet the /out/ in the path, thus they are giving 404 errors.

I tried to follow [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploy-your-nextjs-application-on-a-different-base-path-i-e-not-root-1c4d210cce8a) tutorial, but it looks like I am still doing something wrong,

My next.config.js now is:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, "styles")],
  },

  basePath: "/out",
  assetPrefix: process.env.BASE_PATH || '',
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    basePath: process.env.BASE_PATH || '',
  },
};
```

The relevant piece of the package.json is:

"scripts": {
"dev": "node server.js -p $PORT",
"build": "next build",
"prod": "BASE_PATH=/out next build && next export",
"start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js -p $PORT",
"start2": "next start"
},

The server.js is:

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const keys = require("./server/config/keys");
const stripe = require('stripe')(keys.stripeSecretKey);
const routes = require('./routes');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const app = next({ dir: '.', dev });
const handle = routes.getRequestHandler(app);

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();
        // Static files
        // https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/4.2.3#user-content-static-file-serving-eg-images
    server.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images'), {
        maxAge: dev ? '0' : '365d'
    }));

    server.use(bodyParser.json());

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res)
    });

    server.post('/api/stripe/checkout', async (req, res) => {
        await stripe.charges.create({
            amount: req.body.amount,
            currency: 'usd',
            description: 'Mojosa - React Next Landing Page Templates',
            source: req.body.token.id
        });
        res.send({})
    });

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    server.listen(PORT, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(`> Read on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
    });
})
```

And here is an example of an image in a component:

```
<div className="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    <div className="book-image">
    <img src='/images/book-img.png' alt="image" />
</div>
```

**With this configuration:**

- EXPORT - next build && next export on the /out/ folder are working well when uploaded to the live website, BUT images are giving 404
- DEV or BUILD they are giving 404 and working much worse than the EXPORT site published on the real domain. If I remove `basePath: "/out",` the dev mode works excellent

**Questions:**
How can I make the /out/ path be added to all the images/assets?
I am ok to re-add basePath: "/out",` when exporting.

Comment: I found this link useful https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploy-your-nextjs-application-on-a-different-base-path-i-e-not-root-1c4d210cce8a

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just ran into this one too. You'll need to manually prefix anything in your public folder with your basePath (images, fonts etc)

[Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix)
"Files in the public folder; if you want to serve those assets over a CDN, you'll have to introduce the prefix yourself"

```
<div className="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    <div className="book-image">
    <img src={`${process.env.BASE_PATH}/images/book-img.png`} alt="image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a solution for this for loading fonts and images in css? Since environment variables are not accessible there, the suggested solution isn't possible.

Comment: You need to set this in `next.config.js` as:
    `publicRuntimeConfig: { basePath: process.env.BASE_PATH || '' }`
So it can be accessed as:
    `import getConfig from 'next/config'; const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()`