# Is there a way to set prefix for all local images in next js using next.config.js?

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I have setup my next js code with some static images into the system which is used as

```html
<Image
  height={50}
  width={140}
  alt="Alt"
  objectFit="contain"
  src="/images/logo.png"
/>
```

but now I have to deploy it with `basePath: '/product`. Urls are working fine but images are not loading and I need to use `/product/images/logo.png` before every src.

Is there a way to set in next.config.js and I don't have to change it for the every single image in the system?

Comment: Most probably no. There is this `assetPrefix` thing but it also doesn't work with static files stored in the public directory. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65113234. I don't think there is any feasible option other than find and replace. For future projects, try using the new static image imports instead. They will not require such things whenever `basePath` is changed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not aware about new static image imports. Can you paste a link here for other users as well?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#image-imports